# js.erb file not rendering its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to render a google chart using js.erb. I make a POST request from a python script, to send some parameters to my ruby on rails app which parses those parameters and uses them to show the graph i want but it does not show anything.

```
  params_list = []
        params.each_pair {|key, value|
          params_list.push([key,value])
        }
        p params_list

        @image = Gchart.pie_3d(:size => '500x300',
                  :title => "Top 5 Results",
                  :legend => ["#{params_list[0][0]} #{params_list[0][1]}%" , 'source-document2 [22%]','source-document3','source-document4','source-document5'],
                  :data => [22, 21, 20, 18, 19])

        render :template => "deploy/results.js.erb", :locals => {:image => @image }
```

**results.js.erb**

```
$("#chart").append("<p> <%= escape_javascript render(partial: 'home/chart', locals: { :image => @image }) %> </p> ");
```

but nothing shows up even though in console it says

`Rendered deploy/results.js.erb`

Rails console output

```
Started POST "/results.js" for 131.227.46.134 at 2016-05-14 03:18:13 +0100

Processing by DeployController#results as JS
  Parameters: {"results"=>"[('source-document01348.txt', 22), ('source-document01389.txt', 21), ('source-document01253.txt', 20),
 ('source-document01306.txt', 19), ('source-document01255.txt', 18)]"}
  Rendered home/_chart.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered deploy/results.js.erb (1.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 8.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

python code for post request

```
def send_results(results):
    url = "http://e786a82b.ngrok.io/results.js"
    data = {
        "results": results
    }
    data = urllib.urlencode(data)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data)

    # try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url, data)
```

note: using ngrok to create a tunnel, as python does not send to localhost

Comment: Can you show the output from the POST that you receive in your python script?  And can you show the entire output for the action?

Comment: @MichaelGaskill i posted the rails output when it receives the post request, do not mind rendered home_chart, i just changed my javascript code in js.erb to render partial.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of explicitly referring to your partial by filename, try this:

```
render "deploy/results", :formats => [:js], :locals => {:image => @image }
```

Rails doesn't know what you're trying to render by filename, it does it by context and format.  Specifying the `:formats` option helps Rails to know your intent.

Comment: still not working, in console i see it rendered but it does not show anything. Also this goes on even if i just type alert("test"), it wont do anything. EDIT: if i try to just have a button with remote: true to trigger this action it works. Guess its something to do that i make a post request from the python script?

Comment: Rails uses CSRF token protection to prevent cross-site scripting to send posts.  It's possible that's what's causing the issue, but I would have expected it to signal an error in that case.

Comment: i already bypassed that using `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`, the thing is i get the parameters, its just that for some reason i cannot execute the js.erb code which is really frustrating been going for 2 hours now.

Comment: When you say that you get "nothing", what does that mean?  No response, just hangs?  Headers, but no body?  Headers, but an empty body?  Is there an HTTP status code?

Comment: I sent the parameters via post request from python to rails app. Rails app takes them, assigns them to the @image variable which gets passed to the js.erb file and from there to the partial, which will render an `image_tag @image`, while in console it says rendered js.erb and _chart partial, i do not see any changes in the browser BUT when i do a test run using a test button from the rails up using `remote: true` using mockup data, everything works and shows up, how is that possible?

Comment: I think that it might be something to do with interpretation of the results from the python script.  That's why I was asking what *exactly* you see in python.  HTTP status?  Headers?  Body content?  Multi-part MIME?  Anything at all, or just oblivion?

Comment: Hmm i think i now know why its not working. Its because on the Ruby on Rails response to the python script, it sends the javascript code rather than rendering it in the ruby on rails app, any clues on how to fix that?

Comment: No, Rails doesn't render Javascript, it just delivers it.  The receiver should know how to render it.  If you need something rendered on the Rails server, it's best that it be done in Ruby, and not Javascript.  Maybe consider a Node.js program to call the Rails app, since Node.js can render Javascript when it receives it.